# JQuery: Creating Extension return variable undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a simple an image drag-n-drop jquery extension. What it does is you drag one file and it shows a preview of the file then returns a object with the file name and the image data to be sent via ajax POST.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.dnd = function()
{
    jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');

    $(this).bind('drop',function(e){
        var files       = e.dataTransfer.files;
        var $preview    = $(this);
        var result      = [];

        if(files.length > 1)
        {
            $(this).html('One file only');
            return false;
        }

        if(files[0].type === 'image/png'  || 
           files[0].type === 'image/jpeg' ||
           files[0].type === 'image/ppeg')
        {
            var fileReader      = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload   = (function(f)
            {
                return function(e)
                {
                    result.push({name:f.name,value:this.result});
                    $preview.removeAttr('style');
                    $preview.html('<img src="'+ this.result +'" width="80%"/>');
                };
            })(files[0]);
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).html('images only. GIF not allowed.');
            return false;
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        return result;
    });

};
}(jQuery));
```

I execute the code in this manner.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var result = $('#ec-drag-n-drop').dnd();
   console.log(result);
}
```

When I look at the console it return 'undefined'. Am i missing something?

Comment: Have you checked the selector?
iow, does jquery find your object with just this code: $('#ec-drag-n-drop'). Also, have you been able to debug your dnd function?

Comment: The code works fine. It previews the image correctly. I need the data so that I can pass it to my ajax post to be processed in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You don't return a result.

This code:

```
e.preventDefault();
return result;
```

Happens within your callback to `$(this).bind('drop')`.

So you'll need to provide a callback through your own plugin:

```
$.fn.dnd = function(callback)
{
    jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');

    $(this).bind('drop',function(e){
        // Your code
        callback(result);
    }
}
```

In your main page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#ec-drag-n-drop').dnd(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
   });
}
```

Comment: When I do that. When i remove the prevent default, I get redirected to the image I dragged.

Comment: Leave the `preventDefault` in. If you want to return the result to the `drop` event, you can also leave the return in, but you need to put the callback before it

Comment: I am still getting and empty array. I think it has to do with the scope? I put the data in the fileReader.onload part.